# Target all selected Illustrator objects, or target all objects if none are selected

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

How can I target an Adobe Illustrator script to limit itself to the user's selection if anything is selected, or to run on all objects if nothing is selected?

`app.activeDocument.selection` is often used to target the current selection but is empty if there's no selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.activeDocument.pageItems` is where to access all items as if everything was selected. So, this one liner:

```
var scope = app.activeDocument.selection.length ? app.activeDocument.selection : app.activeDocument.pageItems;
```

...sets the variable `scope` to be the selection if there is one, or everything if there is none. Its contents can then be cycled through the normal way, for example:

```
for(var i=0;i<scope.length;i++){
  // do things with scope[i]
}
```